# Using constrained generics to return a collection of subtypes as a collection of base types. Compiler not able to infer,why?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

So I've come across an issue where the compiler is telling me I can't do something that I think I should be able to do. I've simplified it down and the code is below

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<BaseInterface> GetSubInterfaceImplementers<T>()
        where T : BaseInterface
    {
        return GetThings().OfType<T>();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<BaseInterface> GetThings()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<BaseInterface>();
    }
}

public interface BaseInterface { }

public interface SubInterface1 : BaseInterface { }

public interface SubInterface2 : BaseInterface{ }
```

So this line `return GetThings().OfType<T>();` is giving me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StackOverflowQuestions.BaseInterface>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

In short it is saying it cannot cast `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<BaseInterface>` even though I explicitly said T must be of Type BaseInterface.

If in that method I change the code to read like this

```
return GetThings().OfType<SubInterface1>();
```

It compiles so it clearly doesn't have an issue returning a sub type thanks to IEnumerable being 'Co' or 'Contra' variant (I can never remember).

So why wont it compile??

Explicit casting works, like this:

```
return (IEnumerable<BaseInterface>)GetThings().OfType<T>();
```

but why can't the compiler infer it

Comment: It seems adding `where T : class, ...` helps so it might be because the exact working of this type of conversion depends on whether the compiler knows it will be a class or not.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `static IEnumerable<T> GetSubInterfaceImplementers<T>()
            where T : BaseInterface
        {
            return GetThings().OfType<T>();
        }`?

Comment: Though that error message is correct, it could be a lot more clear. Sorry about that! You might consider entering an issue on the roslyn github site, and perhaps someone can improve it so that the error notes that the reason the conversion does not work is because of the restriction on covariance.

Comment: @EricLippert Can't ask for much more than an apology straight from source ;) but yeah I might stick something on the guthub issues to see if some one clever can make it tell me why I'm wrong

Comment: The easiest thing for the compiler developer to do is to simply state which rule of the language was violated: *you're implicitly converting from X to Y and there is no such conversion*. What is much harder is to *deduce the mental state and the intentions of the developer from the wrong code* and give an error message customized to that scenario. I did a lot of the latter work for LINQ. When you say `from c in customers select c.FristName` the easy thing is to say that there's no overload of `Select` that works with arguments `(customers, c=>c.FristName)` !

Comment: But of course that is not what the developer wants or needs to hear. Similarly, we don't want to say that overload resolution failed because type inference failed. What we want to say is that `FristName` is a typo of `FirstName`.   And C# does a good job of that, but it was a lot of work. We didn't put anything even close to a similar amount of work  into covariance related error messages, and it shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covariance only works with reference types.

Your generic constraint must also specify that T is a reference type (class)

```
static IEnumerable<BaseInterface> GetSubInterfaceImplementers<T>()
        where T : class, BaseInterface
{
        return new GetThings().OfType<T>();
}
```